# What is the preferred way (better style) to name a namespace in Ruby? Singular or Plural?

Tags: ruby, module, namespaces, naming-conventions, naming

What are for you the pros and cons of using:

```
FooLib::Plugins
FooLib::Plugins::Bar
```

vs.

```
FooLib::Plugin
FooLib::Plugin::Bar
```

naming conventions? And what would you use or what are you using? What is more commonly used in the comunity?

Comment: By looking at [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord.html), I see there are more plural names on modules than in classes (see namespaces, at page's second half). However, I don't have enough experience with Rails to get when to use one and when to use the other.

Answer (score 26):

Use:

```
module FooLib end
module FooLib::Plugins end
class  FooLib::Plugins::Plugin; end #the base for plugins
class  FooLib::Plugins::Bar < FooLib::Plugins::Plugin; end
class  FooLib::Plugins::Bar2 < FooLib::Plugins::Plugin; end
```

or in a different words:

```
module FooLib
  module Plugins
    class Plugin; end #the base for plugins
    class Bar < Plugin; end
    class Bar2 < Plugin; end
  end
end
```

Also arrange the files like this:

```
- foo_lib/
  - plugins/
    - plugin.rb
    - bar.rb
    - bar2.rb
```

This is [how Rails does it](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord.html) (so this is the Rails Way). I.e. look at the Associations namespace and the [Associations::Association class](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e1a882a15b71435ec82a596978429b34d4c73ac5/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb) from which all of the classes form the Associations namespace inherits (i.e. [Associations::SingularAssociation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/dfec3737b05d22e6f298bcae0a8948a4b8803ebd/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/singular_association.rb)).

Answer (score 15):

To me `FooLib::Plugins` appears like a module, used as a namespace which various plugin classes are kept in. `FooLib::Plugin` looks like a superclass for FooLib plugins.

In `FooLib::Plugins::Bar`, `Bar` definitely seems like the name of a plugin. With `FooLib::Plugin::Bar`, I would be doubtful whether `Bar` was a helper class used by `Foo::Plugin`, or the name of a plugin.

Comment: This is a general question. Not attached to what I'm doing. I have some thoughts on this topic and I wanted to see what others think about it all.

Comment: What about FooLib::Plugins::Bar vs FooLib::Plugin::Bar? - the second looks to me more like an object name -> Bar is a Plugin in the FooLib, the first fits less this reasoning.

Comment: I personally use `FooLib::Plugin` as the superclass of plugins, and also keep all subclasses under it: `class FooLib::Plugin::Bar < FooLib::Plugin`. It feels natural to read: `Bar` is a `Plugin` in `FooLib`. I think a general class containing its specific subclasses in its own namespace makes a lot of sense. I use this nesting system in all of my code.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `Plugin` is a base class:

- `class FooLib::Plugin::Bar < FooLib::Plugin`

  This is the one I use and recommend. `Bar` is a `Plugin` in `FooLib` *and* it inherits from `FooLib::Plugin`. It also keeps the plugins provided by the `FooLib` library nested under the namespace of the general class, which reads naturally:

  ```
  # Assign the Bar Plugin of the FooLib library to p.
  p = FooLib::Plugin::Bar
  ```

  If I were to develop a third party plugin for your library, I would create the following structure:

  ```
  # Baz is a Plugin for the FooLib library provided by BarLib.
  class BarLib::FooLib::Plugin::Baz < ::FooLib::Plugin
  ```

  Note that I mirror the `FooLib` hierarchy, but under `BarLib`'s namespace. I would not extend it directly.
- `class FooLib::Plugins::Bar < FooLib::Plugin`

  I have also used this one, and I think it makes the most sense. `Bar` extends `FooLib::Plugin` and is one of the `Plugins` provided by `FooLib`. However, it creates a potentially needless module.

  I think this would be a great choice if `Plugins` was a central plugin repository that implements methods like `Plugins.add`, `Plugins.all` and `Plugins.loaded`.

  Use it if you can justify the extra module.
- `class FooLib::Plugins::Bar < FooLib::Plugins`

  Doesn't make a lot of sense to me. `Bar` is one of the `Plugins` in `FooLib`, that part looks fine. However, it inherits from `Plugins`. Is it inheriting from more than one plugin? It sounds strange to me; the class name shouldn't suggest something that is impossible.

Comment: Many good points made, +1. If the plugins don't inherit from a common base class, `FooLib::Plugins` seems very attractive.

Answer (score 2):

I would second the approach outlined by @jtrim.

Given that the module (i.e. Plugin) is being used for namespacing only, I typically override the new method in the module:

```
module Foo
  module Plugin

    def self.included(base)
      raise "cannot be included"
    end

    def self.extended(base)
      raise "cannot extend"
    end

    def self.new(*args)
      Base.new(*args)
    end

    class Base;end
  end
end


base_plugin_obj = Foo::Plugin.new(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the approach I tend to take is:

```
module Foo
  module Plugin
    class Base; end
  end
end

class Foo::Plugin::Bar < Foo::Plugin::Base; end
```

The `Base` class for plugins is a convention found all over the place in the RubyOnRails codebase as well as many others. (e.g. `ActiveRecord::Base`, `ActionController::Base`, etc.)

I disagree with @Matheus Moreira's approach where `Foo::Plugin` is used both as the base class and the namespace for plugins.

The only functional reason why this shouldn't be done has to do with convention - in the Ruby community one will find many less instances of classes as namespaces than modules. The only time I really see classes used as a namespace for another class is when the purpose of said class is private to the namespace class and is not used externally.