# Should Rails nested models be plural namespaced or singular?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating models that are specific to another model (which will ultimately be embedded in the parent model using Mongoid). Now I'm just stuck with trying to figure out how to name them. I've seen it done both ways, so I don't know what to do:

Singular:

```
models/
  post.rb
  post/
    comment.rb
    comment/
      happy_comment.rb

class Post

class Post::Comment

class Post::Comment::HappyComment < Post::Comment
```

Plural:

```
models/
  post.rb
  posts/
    comment.rb
    comments/
      happy_comment.rb

class Post

class Posts::Comment

class Posts::Comments::HappyComment < Posts::Comment
```

The benefit to the later is that there can be `Posts` and `Comments` modules for wrapping around each child model:

```
module Posts
  module Comments
    class HappyComment < Comment
```

What is the correct way to namespace these child models?

Comment: I prefer plural form.

Comment: Why do you prefer the plural form?

Comment: Andrew: `comments` makes a better folder name than `comment`.

Comment: you may also inspect http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293023/what-is-the-preferred-way-better-style-to-name-a-namespace-in-ruby-singular-o

Comment: or http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/75919/should-package-names-be-singular-or-plural

Comment: This isn't a question about preference or general best practices. This is a question about the correct Rails implementation.

Comment: You can't have a class Post and a module Post, right? Anyway, I might like `class PostComment` over namespacing.

Answer (score 2):

There is no generally accepted convention for this and you can use both, depending on what you find better. From technical point of view, Rails will not behave differently in the two situations.

P.S. Are you going to also have other models, named `Post`, `Comment` etc.? If not, than maybe the best approach is to just have each model at the top level of your `models/` folder.